# JDBC connection driver issue in eclipse

Tags: jdbc

I am working on jdbc connection and I am using eclipse. I have placed **connection driver** that is **mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar** file in **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib** folder.  After that I am writing this code to simply create and test connection between application and driver

```
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;

    public class implementation {

        public static void main(String[]arg)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("conneting to driver...");
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
                System.out.println("Connection Successful");

            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException error)
            {
                System.out.println("Error:" + error.getMessage()); 
            }
        }

    }
```

when I am running this program, I am getting this error.

connecting to driver.

**Error:com.mysql.jdbc.driver**

can you please help to solve this issue. thank you for giving me your important time.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318382/class-not-found-exception-for-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-a-classpath-problem

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting ClassNotFoundException because the correct driver class name is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and not com.mysql.jdbc.driver.

The 'D' of Driver is capital(standard Camel Case notation)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry buddy, i cant vote u up becoz dont have that much reputation .. but really want to vote u up.. +1 from my side :D

Answer (score 0):

Add that jar file to BuildPath of the project.

Right Click on the project  --> BuildPath -- Configure builaPath -->Add external jars.

Because You are not running a web application.

Comment: but I am creating a **dynamic web application**

Comment: But you have main method?

Comment: I tried your suggestion of putting .jar file into BuildPath but having save problem.. :'(

Comment: Thnk u PSR for your important time, I have solved the problem with the help of #vagabondtechie (last answer) proble is in this line... Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver"); this line should be like Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
```

By typing driver name manually like above, we are getting `ClassNotFoundException` because of small spell mistakes

That's why always better to use when the fully qualified class name is the input for method

for example,

```
Class.forName(Driver.class.getName().toString());
```

*Before this we need to set the mysql-version.jar file into the buid path*